# When can you use "Einrichtung" as a synonym for "Gründung"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The wiktionary.de page for die Einrichtung provides 5 definitions (https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Einrichtung).

The first definition is the following:
die Handlung, etwas zu gründen oder zu erstellen.

I tried to use this meaning in the following sentence: Die Einrichtung der Mannschaft war erfolgreich, weil die Befürworter viele Geld hat.

I was trying to communicate that the 'founding' of the team was successful. My german friend (who corrects my mistakes) was unable to explain why my usage of Einrichtung was incorrect. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: Did you look up the usage of the verb *einrichten*?

Comment: Yes, one of the synonyms for einrichten was organisieren, as well as gründen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*einrichten* has quite a number of meanings, but the general meaning of "gründen" is none of them. Wiktionary's translation is, unfortunately, at least misleading, or even wrong, because it is too general. [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einrichten) has a better explanation:

> *zur öffentlichen Nutzung schaffen*
>
> **Beispiel**
>
> eine Beratungsstelle, einen Pannendienst einrichten

In case you are looking in that direction, the "founding" of something is limited to publicly accessible and (often) funded *organisations*, *services* or *facilities*.

> eine Suppenküche einrichten
>
> ein Kinderhospital einrichten
>
> eine Beratungsstelle einrichten

and even

> eine öffentliche Bedürfnisanstalt einrichten

This obviously doesn't work for football teams.

Comment: *Einrichten* explictly means the "founding" of something from outside. A better translation is "to install".